# Outputting the string rather than value on VBA max function

Tags: excel, vba, function, max

So I have a function to find the max value in several categories. Instead of saving the value to my "max". I want to save the string/text that corresponds to the max value instead. This is what I have:

```
StartCell.Select  
StartCell.Offset(1, 28).Activate  
For i = 1 To Count

Select Case ActiveCell.Value
    Case "XX"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "0"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "DP0"
    DP0Count = DP0Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "DP1"
    DP1Count = DP1Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "DP2"
    DP2Count = DP2Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "VP1"
    VP1Count = VP1Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "VP2"
    VP2Count = VP2Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Case "MP1"
    MP1Count = MP1Count + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End Select Next i

Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(DP0Count, DP1Count, DP2Count, VP1Count, VP2Count, MP1Count)
MsgBox Max
```

I want the output to look something like this,
Max = DP2 instead of the numeric value

Any ideas?

Comment: Since Max outputs `DP2`, you want to show the answer to `DP2Count + 1`?

Comment: Max currently outputs "10", want it to output "DP2"

Comment: Well it's not clear where that string is supposed to be coming from, since you're working off `ActiveCell` and `Offset` values, and keep `Activate`ing cells for some reason.

Comment: Is this a `Function` called `Max` and the `Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(...)` line is assigning the return value? If that's the case, then why do you `MsgBox Max`? Or is `Max` a local variable? Who is Max anyway?

Comment: Yes, i am assigning the return value to "Max". Currrently DP2 has the highest value after it computes the given range. When i msgbox Max, it output the value 10 but I want "DP2" to be assigned to "Max". sorry if this is confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  Not clear how you'd want to deal with ties if there are two or more "max" values.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim arrVals() As Long, arrNames, v As Long, vMax As Long, i As Long, m

    arrNames = Array("DPO", "DP1", "DP2", "VP1", "VP2", "MP1")

    ReDim arrVals(0 To UBound(arrNames))

    Set c = StartCell.Offset(1, 28)

    For i = 1 To Count

        If c.Value = "XX" Or c.Value = "0" Then
            Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            m = Application.Match(c.Value, arrNames, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                arrVals(m - 1) = arrVals(m - 1) + 1
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End If

    Next i

    vMax = Application.Max(arrVals)

    MsgBox arrNames(Application.Match(vMax, arrVals, 0) - 1)


End Sub
```

Comment: in the case of ties, I want it in the following order: MP1> VP2> VP1> DP2> DP1> DP0. any ideas on how I can implement that? thanks again!

Comment: Match should return the first one it finds when checking `vMax` against `arrVals`, so you can order the values in `arrNames` to match your preference...

Comment: Tim, when the whole array is 0, it'll pick the first input on arrNames which is MP1 on my code. Any way you can address that to make it another variable

Comment: Add another name like "No values" to the beginning of `arrNames`